# Exclude opened Workbook / specific files from Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Code, that copies Data from other files and put them in to a table (opened Workbook). How can i exclude opened Workbook (from where i starting the macro) and for example some specific files (C:\Users\Desktop\text.xlsm) from the loop? I tried with If strFile <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then but it doesn't work, it still try to open the opened Workbook.

Here a part of the Code with the Loop:

```
Set oWks0 = ActiveSheet

aCells = Split(Zellen, ",")

iNextLine = iStartZeile

For ialngFolders = LBound(avntFolders) To UBound(avntFolders)

    strFile = Dir$(avntFolders(ialngFolders) & "*.xlsm")



    Do Until strFile = vbNullString


        Set oWkb1 = Workbooks.Open(avntFolders(ialngFolders) & strFile)
        Set oWks1 = oWkb1.Sheets(1)


        For i = 0 To UBound(aCells)
        'If strFile <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then

            oWks0.Cells(iNextLine, iStartSpalte).Offset(0, i).Value = _
                oWks1.Range(aCells(i)).Value

        'End If

        Next



        Call oWkb1.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

        iNextLine = iNextLine + 1

        strFile = Dir$



    Loop

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks.Open is the method to open workbook

**Using**

If strFile <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then

**before the line**

Set oWkb1 = Workbooks.Open(avntFolders(ialngFolders) & strFile)

Comment: its this line: Set oWkb1 = Workbooks.Open(avntFolders(ialngFolders) & strFile) which opens the workbook through the loop. but how to exclude opened at the moment workbook?